# Print leading zeros with C++ output operator?

Tags: c++, formatting, numbers

How can I format my output in C++? In other words, what is the C++ equivalent to the use of `printf` like this:

```
printf("%05d", zipCode);
```

I know I could just use `printf` in C++, but I would prefer the output operator `<<`.

Would you just use the following?

```
std::cout << "ZIP code: " << sprintf("%05d", zipCode) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 119, accepted):

This will do the trick, at least for non-negative numbers<sup>(a)</sup> such as the ZIP codes<sup>(b)</sup> mentioned in your question.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
cout << setw(5) << setfill('0') << zipCode << endl;

// or use this if you don't like 'using namespace std;'
std::cout << std::setw(5) << std::setfill('0') << zipCode << std::endl;
```

The most common IO manipulators that control padding are:

- `std::setw(width)` sets the width of the field.
- `std::setfill(fillchar)` sets the fill character.
- `std::setiosflags(align)` sets the alignment, where align is ios::left or ios::right.

And just on your preference for using `<<`, I'd strongly suggest you look into the `fmt` library (see https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt). This has been a great addition to our toolkit for formatting stuff and is much nicer than massively length stream pipelines, allowing you to do things like:

```
cout << fmt::format("{:05d}", zipCode);
```

And it's currently being targeted by LEWG toward C++20 as well, meaning it will hopefully be a base part of the language at that point (or almost certainly later if it doesn't quite sneak in).

---

<sup>(a)</sup> If you *do* need to handle negative numbers, you can use `std::internal` as follows:

```
cout << internal << setw(5) << setfill('0') << zipCode << endl;
```

This places the fill character *between* the sign and the magnitude.

---

<sup>(b)</sup> This ("all ZIP codes are non-negative") is an assumption on my part but a reasonably safe one, I'd warrant :-)

Comment: Note that you can also just use `cout << left` or `cout << right` for alignment.

Comment: Note that this solution does NOT work correctly for negative numbers! Trying to print "-5" this way results in: "000-5"

Comment: Adding std::internal will make this code correct for negative numbers.

Comment: @Nadav, do you live in an area that has negative ZIP codes? :-) On a more serious note, I'll edit the answer to make that clear.

Comment: Thanks. I actually found your answer looking for a general solution for any integer, including negatives, found your nice highly-ranked answer and I didn't realize that because zip codes were mentioned, the answer assumed the integer was positive. Thanks for editing the answer, it will probably help more people in the future.

Answer (score 16):

In C++20 you can do:

```cpp
std::cout << std::format("{:05}", zipCode);
```

On older systems you can use [the {fmt} library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt), `std::format` is based on.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of {fmt} and C++20 `std::format`.

Comment: More info at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342162/stdstring-formatting-like-sprintf/57286312#57286312

Answer (score 14):

Use the [setw and setfill](http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/io/omanipulators.html) calls:

```
std::cout << std::setw(5) << std::setfill('0') << zipCode << std::endl;
```

Comment: Re-activated and +1'ed since it shows how to do it in any namespace (also added setfill, sqook, hope you don't mind).

Comment: Fair enough.  "using namespace std;" is definitely evil. ;)

Comment: I think this answer should mention that, unlike the setting from `std::setw`, the setting of `std::setfill` will stick after the output is performed, in other words the fill character for `std::cout` will be permanently changed (until modified by another `std::setfill`). As it is unlikely this is desirable, it would seem best to save and restore the previous fill character.

Answer (score 5):

```
cout << setw(4) << setfill('0') << n << endl;
```

from:

http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/io/omanipulators.html

Answer (score 3):

or,

```
char t[32];
sprintf_s(t, "%05d", 1);
```

will output 00001 as the OP already wanted to do

Comment: The OP explicitly asked for a way that uses the `<<` operator instead of (s)printf.

Comment: @jankes that would be :  std::cout << "ZIP code: " <<sprintf_s(t, "%05d", 1)<< endl;

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer but it works!

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const Clock &c){
// format the output - if single digit, then needs to be padded with a 0
int hours = c.getHour();

// if hour is 1 digit, then pad with a 0, otherwise just print the hour
(hours < 10) ? os << '0' << hours : os << hours;

return os; // return the stream
}
```

I'm using a ternary operator but it can be translated into an if/else statement as follows

```
if(c.hour < 10){
 os << '0' << hours;
}
 else{
  os  << hours;
 }
```