# C++ equivalent of sprintf?

Tags: c++, printf

I know that `std::cout` is the C++ equivalent of `printf`.

What is the C++ equivalent of `sprintf`?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

[`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream)

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream> // for ostringstream
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string name = "nemo";
  int age = 1000;
  std::ostringstream out;
  out << "name: " << name << ", age: " << age;
  std::cout << out.str() << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
name: nemo, age: 1000
```

Comment: I don't think that sprintf writes to stdout. I would remove the insertion statement above.

Comment: How is this even remotely similar to `sprintf (...)`? You cannot format the data arbitrarily, you have to rely on the type being known when you feed it into the stream using the `<<` operator.

Comment: I need to agree with @AndonM.Coleman about this one. This is not really a sprintf replacement. [This](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstring.html#arg) would be more like that, but this is Qt.

Comment: as @vinkris says in his answer, iomanip achieves formatting. Instead of printing to stdoit, I would say "result = out.str()".

Comment: sprintf / snprintf allows formating and printing to a user allocated character array, may be on stack. In case of snprintf(), it ensures there is no overrun. Here we are allocating memory multiple times and the caller has no direct access it. Have to convert to a string to get the output. An std::ostream with a custom std::streambuf, which takes user buffer would be a better match - of course construction/destruction of ostream/streambuf adds more in-efficiency.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: You are right, but the context of the answer makes sense when considering the OP's initial sentence.

Comment: @MGH: `<<` supports formatting (e.g. `<< std::hex() << 42`), otherwise these are all features, not bugs. I tend to think that in most `sprintf()` uses, the requirement to manage memory and protect from over-run is a hassle that should be avoided if possible. C++ offers you easier coding practices (optimize for development time) and are usually not that worse off in terms of CPU time. If you need something super-optimized, there are a few options (including writing C-style or even `asm`) otherwise - come to the darkside of idiomatic C++, we have cookies.

Answer (score 44):

Update, August 2019:

It looks like C++20 will have `std::format`. The reference implementation is [{fmt}](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt). If you are looking for a `printf()` alternative now, this will become the new "standard" approach and is worth considering.

Original:

Use [Boost.Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/format/doc/format.html). It has `printf`-like syntax, type safety, `std::string` results, and lots of other nifty stuff. You won't go back.

Comment: ... unless you are concerned about the size of your executable.. :P

Comment: How much of an impact would this have?  The Boost dependency would be header-only, no linking, correct?

Comment: @KenWilliams Yes, Boost.Format is header only. A simple "hello, world" test on my Mac increases from 10kB to 78kB. In a real project the extra size will be amortised across compilation units (give the right linker options), and the type safety brings other benefits.

Comment: When executable size bloats, always try to use shared libraries!

Answer (score 19):

[sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/) works just fine in C++.

Comment: I think the OP meant STL rather than C++.

Comment: sprintf requires you to allocate the character buffer. I would like something like the "append" method of "std::string" that allows me to add formatted data, and taking care of allocating behind the scenes.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a nice function for a c++ sprintf.  Streams can get ugly if you use them too heavily.

```
std::string string_format(std::string fmt, ...) {
    int size=100;
    std::string str;
    va_list ap;

    while (1) {
        str.resize(size);
        va_start(ap, fmt);
        int n = vsnprintf(&str[0], size, fmt.c_str(), ap);
        va_end(ap);
   
        if (n > -1 && n < size) {
            str.resize(n); // Make sure there are no trailing zero char
            return str;
        }
        if (n > -1)
            size = n + 1;
        else
            size *= 2;
    }
}
```

In C++11 and later, std::string is guaranteed to use contiguous storage that ends with `'\0'`, so it is legal to cast it to `char *` using `&str[0]`.

Comment: Very nice solution! I've adapted it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3742999/15161 to more closely fit `sprintf`-usage.

Comment: Illegal, though: `(char*) str.c_str()` casts away `const`.

Comment: also there's buffer overflow problem lurking

Comment: @MSalters Correct. There's a legal way to do that in C++11.

Comment: @whitequark: Feel free to add that as an answer. On Stack Overflow, good question remain open to allow new answers.

Comment: Not illegal, no casting problem, and no possible buffer overflow.  Please read the specs.

Comment: Fantastic! You declared `n` twice though

Comment: There is a interesting bug when you try to append something to the result of this function. Took me a while to figure out it was appended at position 100+

Comment: I got `warning: passing an object of reference type to 'va_start' has undefined behavior [-Wvarargs]` on Clang++-10

Comment: @Sapphire_Brick just change the arg to pass fmt by value.   it won't actually copy the string on modern compilers anyway

Answer (score 7):

You can use iomanip header file to format the output stream.
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25120551/463414)!

Comment: Why did somebody downvote this? Isn't iomanip the pure-C++ way of achieving formatting in streams? I think the goal here is to avoid storing data in C-style strings, which is achieved with iomanip.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what exactly you plan on `sprintf()`ing, `std::to_string()` might be useful and more idiomatic than other options:

```cpp
void say(const std::string& message) {
 // ...
}

int main() {
  say(std::to_string(5));
  say("Which is to say " + std::to_string(5) + " words");
}
```

The main advantage of `std::to_string()`, IMHO, is that it can be extended easily to support additional types that `sprintf()` can't even dream of stringifying - kind of like Java's `Object.toString()` method.

Answer (score -1):

Use a stringstream to achieve the same effect. Also, you can include `<cstdio>` and still use snprintf.