# C++: something is getting sent to the console: how do I, instead, store it to a variable?

Tags: c++

```
string convert_binary_to_hex(string binary_value)
{
    bitset<8> set(binary_value);    
    cout << hex << set.to_ulong() << endl; // this is the output that I want to store to a variable to return
    return "";
}
```

I've not really done C before. =D

EDIT:
a user suggested ostringstream:

```
ostringstream result;
bitset<8> set(binary_value);    
result << hex << set.to_ulong() << endl;
return result.str();
```

but it now give this error:

```
main.cpp:20: error: aggregate ‘std::ostringstream result’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined
```

Also, my imports:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>


using namespace std;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write it to an instance of `std::ostringstream`:

```
string convert_binary_to_hex(string binary_value)
{
    bitset<8> set(binary_value);    
    ostringstream oss;
    oss << hex << set.to_ulong() << endl; // this is the output that I want to store to a variable to return
    return oss.str();
}
```

Comment: like... ostringstream varName instead of cout?

Comment: @DerNalia I've expanded the answer.

Comment: I am getting this error though: main.cpp:20: error: aggregate ‘std::ostringstream result’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined

Comment: I have updated my question to help others having this problem

Comment: oops, I need  #include <sstream>

Answer (score 0):

See this answer:

[C++ equivalent of sprintf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983092/c-equivalent-to-sprintf/4983095#4983095)

And use the `out` variable like you're using `cout` here, and instead of

```
std::cout << out.str() << '\n';
```

you would just do

```
return out.str();
```