# sprintf' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char *' to 'char *'

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
std::string mystring;

sprintf(mystring.c_str(), "%s %d", "Helloworld", 2014);
```

Its is giving a compiler error to me:

`'sprintf' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char *' to 'char *'`

Comment: first parameter of sprintf should be a char * but you are passing const char *.  **mystring.c_str()**  is const char *. you can use append  to do whatever you want to do with sprintf  **mystring.append("Helloworld 2014");**

Comment: First argument of "sprintf" is a pointer to character array 'char *' where the formatted string will be saved. In the other hand, mystring.c_str() is a contant character array which is generated from mystring. Data type of them is different.

Answer (score 10):

It shouldn't be a warning, it should be an error.  The pointer
returned by `std::string::c_str()` points to read-only memory;
any attempt to write through it is undefined behavior.  (In your
case, if you use a `const_cast` to shut up the compiler, you're
code will probably crash, since you're calling `c_str()` on an
empty strying.)

Generally speaking, what you probably want is
`std::ostringstream`:

```
std::ostringstream formatter;
formatter << "Helloworld" << ' ' << 2014;
std::string myString = formatter.str();
```

FWIW: `sprintf` is one of the most dangerous functions in the
standard library, and only present for historical reasons.  It's
almost impossible to use safely; even in C, you should prefer
`snprintf` (but in C++, `std::ostringstream` is far better).

Answer (score 9):

your warning gives you all information you need.

`std::string::c_str()` returns a `const char*` and sprintf requires a `char*` since it modiefies the buffer.

But you are writing c++ and should avoid sprintf. Use a `ostringstream` to write formated data to a string.

Comment: It's `std::string::c_str()`.  And he should use `std::ostringstream` for writing, not `std::stringstream`.

Comment: @JamesKanze yes i corrected the typo. With 'stringstream' i meant more the concept than the specific class. Otherwise i had used backticks - but i will add too.

Answer (score 2):

`std::string` manages underlying C-style buffer. `c_str` returns const char* because it shouldn't be modified by anything other then string's methods.

You should rather use `ostringstream`. See this question: [C++ equivalent of sprintf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983092/c-equivalent-of-sprintf)

Answer (score 2):

You are telling sprintf to store the result in `mystring.c_str()`. This is a readonly view of the underlying representation of `mystring`. Since it is readonly (or `const char *`), you can't write the result to it.

If you need to use sprintf, you will have to create a writable character buffer for it to use, and then assign that buffer to mystring.

A different way of performing this sort of operation without having to create character buffers and deal with possible overflow would be to use a `stringstream`:

```
std::stringstream buffer;
buffer << "Helloworld " << 2014;
mystring = buffer.str();
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, use old C [snprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/) into a temporary buffer, then assign into the string :

```
 std::string mystring;
 char buf[64];
 snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%s %d", "Helloworld", 2014);
 mystring.assign(buf);
```

<sup>`snprintf` is always safer than `sprintf` since it avoids [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow).</sup>

But of course using an `ostringstream` like answered [here by James Kanze](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26033552/841108) is better.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>  

 std::stringstream ss;
 ss << "Helloworld";
 ss << " ";
 ss << "2014";
 ss << std::endl;
 std::string str = ss.str();
 std::cout << str;

 const char * mystring= str.c_str();
```

In this way also you can append int or long number into the string.

Example:

```
 long year = 2014;

 std::stringstream ss;
 ss << "Helloworld";
 ss << " ";
 ss << year;
 ss << std::endl;
 std::string str = ss.str();
 std::cout << str;

 const char * mystring= str.c_str();
```