# print BCD value with itoa

Tags: c++, encoding, itoa

I need to print on screen a variable value that is encoded in BCD.

Do you know whether is possible to print it on screen by using `itoa`?

If that is possible, how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `itoa` will not help. You want to look at the hexadecimal representation, so use `hex` like in  `cout << hex << n << endl;`

Note: BCD codes the digits as 4-bit-sequences 0000 to 1001, which in hexadecimal are 0 to 9.
So 23 as BCD would be `0010 0011` bitwise, or in fact as  8bit integer it would be 35, so converting this to a string will not be of much use.

Comment: and if you want to know how to print this to a string, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100718/int-to-hex-string-in-c