# How to convert decimal to hex in C++ JNI

Tags: c++, java-native-interface, hex, decimal

Current convert decimal to hex in C#, i using code :

```
private string Dec2Hex(int value)
{
    return value.ToString("X2");
}
```

Please help port to C++ Jni. Thanks

Comment: [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf)? [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Integer to hex string in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100718/integer-to-hex-string-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

so decimal to hex goes this way, if this helps you

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss<< std::hex << decimal_value;
std::string res ( ss.str() );
std::cout << res;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int value = Convert.ToInt32(/*"HexValue"*/);
String hexRepresentation = Convert.ToString(value, 16);
```