# Convert decimal VALUE(not string) to hexadecimal in C++

Tags: function, hex

I have a decimal value stored in DWORD, and I want to convert it in simple way to hex to send it as argument to another function.

Is there any efficient function to do it or I have to write it myself?

I don't need to print it - I need the hex value in DWORD variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integer to hex string in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100718/integer-to-hex-string-in-c)

Comment: "I don't need to print it - I need the hex value in DWORD variable" is an idiotic requirement. The proposed duplicate makes it a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
int numToConvert = 15;
std::cout << std::hex << numToConvert << endl;
```

This should give you hex of 15.