# Arduino C function to convert String to HEX?

Tags: c++, c, arduino, itoa

I am looking for built-in C or C++ function that allows me to convert a float into an HEX string, so far I have used `itoa` , but it does not work with negative values since it works with unsigned for base 16, so I was wondering which one I could use instead that may handle the negative value.

Using itoa I loose my negative value as it can be seen below,

```
Acceleration X: -9 | X angle: **-0.5156689167**
Acceleration Y: -69 | Y angle: **-3.9565520286**
Acceleration Z: 986 | Z angle: 80.4013519287
Value of ACC per axe (x,y,z) in HEX ->ffcdfe751f68
Data to be send x ->**ffcd**
Data to be send y ->**fe75**
Data to be send z ->1f68
```

What other function could I use with the same functionality?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100718/integer-to-hex-string-in-c

Comment: @Marco thanks, I saw that solution what I am not sure whether it will work in Arduino or not.

Comment: If you're not sure,  try it out.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by converting a floating-point number to hex? Can't you just send the `float` as four data bytes?

Comment: @MOehm what that format is for printf right? The problem in here lies on the fact that I have to pass on the data in hex format to the function that will send it out

Comment: It is not clear what you need exactly. Do you send a string that contains a hex representation of the floating-point number? If so, can't the string contain arbitrary data? Or is the string really just an array of bytes, that is, any data? I ask because I have the feeling that you are barking up the wrong tree with your request to convert a float to hex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the results you provided I would say they are correct. You got the binary complement values:

```
ffcd = -51 in 16-Bit binary complement
fe75 = -395 in 16-Bit binary complement
1f68 = 8040 in 16-Bit binary complement
```

Devide it by 100 and you get your (rounded) floating point values.

atoi can handle negative values. It indicates the negative status by setting the most valued Bit of the binary representation to 1. You will not get a - sign, if you did expect one.

You can compute the binary complement by yourself by converting the (16-Bit) HEX value to a decimal and substract 65536 from the result.

e.g

```
ffcd -dec-> 65485 -sub-> 65485 - 65536 = -51 -float-> -51 / 100.0 = - 0.51
```

Comment: thank you very much I didn't know that itoa was encoding the sign on the most significative bit!! That is perfect!

Comment: @ Peter Paul Kiefer another question popped my up in my head, if the number is not negative, then if I do your procedure it would be wrongly converted, wouldn't it? SO as to check whether or not is negative I should check always the most significative bit of the number, right?

Comment: @ndarkness , I solved my question by using `strtol` to convert from HEX to dec

Comment: @ndarknes Sorry, I'm a bit late. Yes you are right. A positive number can be identified by a zero in the most significant bit or if the first hex digit is less than 8. The example I provide only works on negative numbers. For positive numbers you must not substract 65536 from the decimal result. And it isa good idea to use a library function (strtol) to convert to a decimal.