# Converting an int to a char array with a chosen format

Tags: c++, windows, format

I have an int which I want to convert to a char array, but I want the char array to be formatted in hexadecimal and with every byte of the int taking up exactly 2 char variables (filled out with zeroes).

To clarify what I mean, I have an example:

I want the int 232198 (0x38b06) to become "00038b06".

I can of course acomplish this by using this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::cout << 
    std::hex << 
    std::setw(8) << 
    std::setfill('0') << 
    232198 <<
    std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Which prints out:

> 00038b06

But that only prints it out to the console, and as I mentioned before, want to store it a char array.

I don't care if the code is portable or not, this just has to work for windows.

Comment: Seek ye the fabled `std::stringstream`.

Comment: You can find help in:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100718/integer-to-hex-string-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream)s are useful to do this:

```
std::stringstream sstr;
sstr << 
    std::hex << 
    std::setw(8) << 
    std::setfill('0') << 
    232198;
std::string str = sstr.str();
```

now `str` contains the formatted number. `str.c_str()` will give you a `const char*`.