# Hexadecimal representation of an integer to std::string

Tags: c++

I'm writting a dump() method where I concatenate misc values. The problem is that I can't get the std::string with hexadecimal representation of `number` so I can append it to a result string.

```
    std::string dump() {
        std::string result;
        ...
        result.append(", number=0x");
        result.append(std::to_string(number));  // WRONG - hex rep. desired here
        ...
        return result;
    }
```

Can you support how to achieve this?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100718/integer-to-hex-string-in-c