# C++ printing out a decimal value as hex value

Tags: c++, formatting

I am trying to write an integer decimal value as hex value in C++, but the code below writes the hex value seperated( see the attached image). I want to write it on left and not-seperated. For example if my integer value is 100, its hex value is 0x64 and i want to print out the hex value. Any advise ?

[image: my output]

```
int ia = (int)A;
cout << left << "0x" << setw(sizeof(ia)*2) << hex << uppercase << ia << endl;
```

I am trying to write an integer value with hex value in C++, but the code below writes the hex value seperated( see the attached image). I want to write it on left and not-seperated.

Comment: Please [don't show images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Copy-paste text *as text* into your questions.

Comment: ```cout << "0x" << hex << ia << '\n';```

Comment: [`std::setfill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill)?

Comment: Why are you using the `setw` manipulator? What is the actual output you want, `0x64` or zero-padded like `0x00000064`? Or something else? Please [edit] your question to tell us.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100718/integer-to-hex-string-in-c

Comment: If you haven't figured it out yet: Don't use `left` or `setw`. That's all you need to do. Those manipulators are just not needed for this use-case.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what you want is something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
  int ia = 42;
  const auto save_flags = std::cout.flags();
  std::cout
    << std::left
    << std::showbase
    << std::hex
    << std::uppercase
    << std::setfill('0')
    << std::setw(std::numeric_limits<decltype(ia)>::digits / 4)
    << ia
    << std::endl;
  std::cout.flags(save_flags);
}
```

This will first of all save the existing flags of the `std::cout` stream so that you can restore them later after you have manipulated them. Then it will print the number left aligned (`std::left`) and it will show the base of the number you are printing (`0X` for hex - this is the `std::showbase` bit), it will print the number as hex (`std::hex`) in uppercase (`std::uppercase`) and it will use `0` to fill any missing digits (`std::setfill('0')` up to your desired width (which I made the maximum number of digits for the given type - the `std::setw(std::numeric_limits<decltype(ia)>::digits / 4)` bit). Finally we restore the previous flags of the stream so future prints get the normal (or at least previously set) flags.

### C++23

Starting from C++23, you can get rid of iostreams and use the [`std::print`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/print) funtion for formatting and printing purposes.

```
#include <print>
#include <limits>


int main( )
{
    int ia { 42 };

    std::print( "{:0<#{}X}\n", ia,
                std::numeric_limits<decltype( ia )>::digits / 4 );
}
```

Output:

```bash
0X2A000
```

**Explanation:** Here in `"{:0<#{}X}\n"`, **0** is the fill character. **<** is the left alignment symbol. **#** adds **0X** to the beginning of the number. And **X** is the format specifier for uppercase hex integer formatting.

Comment: I want to see from the output "0x64", not "0x640000000". And x will not be upper case, it should be lowercase (0x64 not 0X64).

Comment: I don't want to use print function, just cout.

Comment: @Eray Check this one: [link](https://godbolt.org/z/eqcMPTn8T).

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is to use `setbase(16)` or its equivalent `hex`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<iomanip>

int main() {

    int ia = (int)100;
    std::cout << std::left << "0x" << std::hex << ia << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::setbase(16)` is equivalent to `std::hex`, so the difference to the OP code is dropping `std::setw()`.

Comment: its output is still "0x         64", but i need "0x64".

Comment: Not sure why.  I get:  0x64.  I've updated the sample code to be the complete program.

Comment: I've updated the answer to use std:hex rather than std::base(16) as that's what the original question had.  thanks for the info Nielsen.