# sprintf to std::string directly?

Tags: c++, performance, printf, stdstring

I'm interested (for various reasons) format using sprintf with the result in a `std::string` object. The most syntactically direct way I came up with is:

```
char* buf;
sprintf(buf, ...);
std::string s(buf);
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you aware that your code as is causes a buffer overflow or is this a genuine bug in the code you’re using at the moment?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [std::string formatting like sprintf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342162/stdstring-formatting-like-sprintf)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use the `printf` line of functions for formatting in C++. Use the language feature of streams (stringstreams in this case) which are type safe and don't require the user to provide special format characters.

If you *really really* want to do that, you could pre-allocate enough space in your string and then resize it down although I'm not sure if that's more efficient than using a temporary char buffer array:

```
std::string foo;
foo.resize(max_length);
int num_bytes = snprintf(&foo[0], max_length, ...);
if(num_bytes < max_length)
{
    foo.resize(num_bytes);
}
```

Comment: I think I heard once that the elements of `basic_string` are not guaranteed to be contiguous, and so using `&foo[0]` like this would technically be undefined behavior.  I also *think* I heard this was changed in C++11, I'm not sure though.

Comment: @Benjamin : C++03 proper does not require contiguous storage for `std::basic_string<>`, but [library issue 530](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#530) requires it and every compiler vendor I'm aware of has adhered to this for years. Also, you're correct that C++11 requires it.

Comment: Should `max_length` count the terminating null byte, then? I think I heard once that `basic_string` does not use null-termination.

Comment: The stream interface is not internationalizable. BTW. You can get the length of a string by passing a NULL pointer to snprintf.

Answer (score 1):

If you **absolutely** want to use `sprintf`, there is no more direct way than the one you wrote.

> sprintf Writes into the array pointed by str a C string

If you want to transform this `C string` into a `std::string`, there is no better and safer way than the one you wrote.

Comment: Never advocate `sprintf` when `snprintf` is available on almost every system (assuming C++ streams aren't an option).

Answer (score 1):

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32821650/2622016). To get length of buffer needed, call:

```
snprintf( nullptr, 0, format, args... )
```

You can write short function which can be used as such:

```
std::string s = string_sprintf("%g, %g\n", 1.23, 0.001);
```

Example in linked stackoverflow answer.