# Create multiple directoris in a for loop in c++ on windows

Tags: c++, windows, string, string-formatting

I'm trying to make a program which will create a sum of directories the user wants to create.

this is my code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include<windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])    {

    int nrDirs = 0;
    cin>> nrDirs;

    for (int i = 0; i <= nrDirs; i++) {
             CreateDirectory ("C:\\Users\\myName\\Desktop\\new", NULL);
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Now my problem, I don't know how to rename the directory. I know how to do this in Objective-C:

```
"C:\\Users\\myName\\Desktop\\new%i", i
```

But this don't work in c++. :(

So how do i do this?

Comment: For all practical purposes, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342162/stdstring-formating-like-sprintf

Comment: There's `std::to_string` in C++11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use can use `CString::Format`:

```
dirName.Format("C:\\Users\\myName\\Desktop\\new%i", i);
```

Use can use `std::stringstream`:

```
dirName << "C:\\Users\\myName\\Desktop\\new" << i;
```

Use can use `sprintf`:

```
sprintf(dirName, "C:\\Users\\myName\\Desktop\\new%i", i);
```

For all the above cases, `dirName` is a buffer that you will need to pass to `CreateDirectory`.

If intermediate directories in the path do not exist, use `SHCreateDirectory`. This API also creates intermediate directories in the path if they do not exist.

Comment: For the 3 examples it would be as follows - 1) CString dirName; 2) std::stringstream dirName; 3) char dirName[MAX_PATH];