# Saving hex values to a C++ string

Tags: c++

I have a simple question but was not able to find an answer on the internet.
I am using the native WiFi API of Windows and trying to get the MAC of an access point.

Inside a structure of type WLAN_BSS_ENTRY there is a field named dot11Bssid which is basically an array of 6 unsigned chars.

What I want to do, is to have the MAC address in an std::string like this: 'AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA'.

I can print the adress like this:

```
for (k = 0; k < 6; k++) 
{
    wprintf(L"%02X", wBssEntry->dot11Bssid[k]);
}
```

But I am unable to find a way of moving this values to a string with the format identified above.

Help is appreciated, if you wonder why do i want this in a string, I have the need to compare it with a string formatted that way.
Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: I would investigate `std::stringstream`.

Comment: I know stringstreams but my problem was with the formatting, I did some basic trial and get strange characters, I'll go for swprintf or sprintf I guess. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `std::ostringstream` (as already commented) with the [IO manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip). [For example](http://ideone.com/f2nm7):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <ios>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

int main()  
{
    unsigned char buf[] = { 0xAA, 0xD1, 0x09, 0x01, 0x10, 0xF1 };

    std::ostringstream s;
    s << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::uppercase
      << std::setw(2) << static_cast<int>(buf[0]) << ':'
      << std::setw(2) << static_cast<int>(buf[1]) << ':'
      << std::setw(2) << static_cast<int>(buf[2]) << ':'
      << std::setw(2) << static_cast<int>(buf[3]) << ':'
      << std::setw(2) << static_cast<int>(buf[4]) << ':'
      << std::setw(2) << static_cast<int>(buf[5]);

    std::cout << "[" << s.str() << "]\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It worked well with std::ostringstream and for anyone visiting the question this answer will be really useful, so marked as correct answer! Thanks.

Comment: This is "The Right Way to Do It" for C++, so upvote.  Could be a bit improved with some sort of foreach or range-based for construction as far as verbosity is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume you'd use something similar to sprintf, the std::string class contains a conversion constructor to move from c-strings to std::strings. So you could sprintf(), if that's what you're looking for. You're using wchar types though, so you may want to consider swprintf() instead.

Similar question:
[std::string formatting like sprintf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342162/stdstring-formating-like-sprintf)

Comment: I'll give it a try and tell you how did I do. Thanks!

Comment: When I commented on this, I forgot about `std::stringstream`, it may very well be a better idea to go that route. Regardless, I hope you can get it working! :)

Comment: It worked fine both ways but I'll keep the one with std::stringstream which seems better. For the sake of the site I'll mark the other one as correct but thanks anyway :) .

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with using stringstream, but it's sort of surprising that one would know wprintf without being aware of swprintf. printf is a whole family of functions, not just printf and wprintf:

```
​int printf( const char *format, ... );​
int fprintf( FILE *stream, const char *format, ... );
int sprintf( char *buffer, const char *format, ... );
int snprintf( char *buffer, int buf_size, const char *format, ... );
int wprintf( const wchar_t* format, ... );
int fwprintf( FILE *stream, const wchar_t* format, ... );
int swprintf( char *buffer, const wchar_t* format, ... );
​int vprintf( const char *format, va_list vlist );​
int vfprintf( FILE *stream, const char *format, va_list vlist );
int vsprintf( const char *buffer, const char *format, va_list vlist );
int vsnprintf( char *buffer, int buf_size, const char *format, va_list vlist );
int vwprintf( const wchar_t* format, va_list vlist );
int vfwprintf( FILE* stream, const wchar_t* format, va_list vlist );(2) 
int vswprintf( const wchar_t* buffer, const wchar_t* format, va_list vlist );
```

Comment: It was my bad, it was a long time since I last dealt with C/C++ and was a bit rusty but I was aware of the printf family.

Answer (score 0):

Use some like that

```
int value = 0x1234;
char * temp = new char[100];
sprintf(temp, "0x%x", value);
std::string target(temp);
delete[] temp;
```