# How do I send a format string to iostream?

Tags: c++, iostream, format-string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [std::string formatting  like sprintf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342162/stdstring-formatting-like-sprintf)

Can I use the c++ iostream classes with a format string like printf?

Basically, I want to be able to do something like :-

```
snprintf (inchars, len, "%4f %6.2f %3d \n", float1, float2, int1);
```

easily using stringstreams. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: standard C++ formats are much more verbose, sadly.  You're going to want a library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there's the [Boost Format Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/format/) (which is stringstreams internally).

[Example:](http://ideone.com/om1Ew)

```
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << boost::format("%s %s!\n") % "Hello" % "World";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, what a terrible syntax...

Comment: this looks like it will work... although i'll hold out for a while hoping for a better solution with a cleaner syntax.

Comment: You get used to it ... However, there are rare cases where you can get trouble with operator precedence because of this approach.

Comment: The use of `%` was probably inspired by python

Answer (score 2):

You can write a wrapper function that returns something that you can deliver into an ostringstream.

This function combines some of the solutions presented in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342162/stdstring-formatting-like-sprintf) moooeeeep pointed out in comments:

```
std::string string_format(const char *fmt, ...) {
    std::vector<char> str(100);
    va_list ap;
    while (1) {
        va_start(ap, fmt);
        int n = vsnprintf(&str[0], str.size(), fmt, ap);
        va_end(ap);
        if (n > -1 && n < str.size()) {
            str.resize(n);
            return &str[0];
        }
        str.resize(str.size() * 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: nice. Here's a link to play around: http://ideone.com/23xIY

Comment: I just discovered a downside of this: when you pass in a format string that doesn't match the arguments supplied, you get rather unspecific errors, ranging from printed garbage to segmentation faults. boost::format provides a helpful error message instead. See this: http://ideone.com/63BK1

Comment: @moooeeeep: GCC provides an extension attribute that would warn about mismatched parameters to printf arguments (`__attribute__((format(...)))`).

Answer (score 0):

This kind of formatting takes quite a bit more effort using standard C++ streams. In particular, you have to use [stream manipulators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/) which can specify the number of digits to show after the decimal place.