# How to most efficiently construct a std::string from char * with size

Tags: c++, std, stdstring

I was looking at a way to achieve `sprintf()` functionality with `std::string` and I found a good answer from [std::string formatting like sprintf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8098080/369450). This is somewhat hacky though because it writes directly to the pointer returned from `string.c_str()`. So I reimplemented it using a `char *` with `malloc()` and `realloc()`.

```
std::string string_format(const char * format, ...) {
    size_t size;
    size_t n;
    va_list args;
    char * buffer;
    std::string str;

    size = 100;
    buffer = malloc(size);
    for (;;) {
        va_start(args, format);
        n = vsnprintf(buffer, size, format, args);
        va_end(args);
        if (n > -1) {
            if (n < size) {
                size = n;
                break;
            }
            size = n + 1;
        } else {
            size *= 2;
        }
        buffer = realloc(buffer, size);
    }

    str = std::string(buffer, size);

    free(buffer);
    return str;
}
```

I know I could just do:

```
str = std::string(buffer);
```

But then it will have to essentially do `strlen(buffer)`. I could make it a little better by:

```
str = std::string(buffer, size);
```

But would using `string.swap()` be more efficient by swapping the internal buffer instead of copying it?

```
str.swap(std::string(buffer, size));
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can write to the buffer retrieved by `&str[0]` in C++11 as long as you stop before the null, and don't touch the null at all.

Comment: to add to @chris, you can also use string::reserve to expand it

Comment: It may be worth it to see how [boost format](http://www.boost.org/libs/format/) does it. Also, have you considered using variadic templates instead of varargs?

Comment: Arguably, Yes `swap` will be more efficient unless you prove otherwise by posting profiling data for both the cases. And If you are really serious about this being a bottle neck then you should be doing that.

Comment: I think you should profile your program, to see if this is really a bottleneck.

Comment: I'm aware that this won't likely be a bottleneck, it's more for curiosities sake.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just use `str.assign(buffer, size);`