# C++ variable arguments with std::string only

Tags: c++11, stdstring, variadic-functions, printf

I'm trying to create a function that takes a variable amount of std::string arguments and formats a string with it.

Example:

```
Test::formatLine(const string::format, ...)
{
    const std::string buffer;
va_list args;
va_start(args, format);
vsprintf(buffer.c_str, format.c_str, args);
va_end(args);
cout << buffer << endl;
}
```

Compiling this snippet errors:

```
Error   1   error C3867: 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::c_str': function call missing argument list; use '&std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::c_str' to create a pointer to member
```

What I want to achieve:

```
Test t = Test();
t.formatLine("Hello %s!", "monsieur");
```

should print `Hello monsieur!`

```
t.formatLine("Hello %s %s! How %s you today?", "good", "sir", "are");
```

should print `Hello good sir! How are you today?`

Is it even possible to use `va_list` and `vsprintf` with `std::string` only, avoiding `char buffer[size]`?

Working example (so far) with fixes suggested by Igor, using buffer:

```
void Test::formatLine(string format, ...)
{
    char buffer[256];
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    vsprintf_s(buffer, format.c_str(), args);
    va_end(args);
    cout << buffer << endl;
}
```

Using **Igor Tandetnik**'s suggestion and sample code I finally got a working example that does not use char buffer[size]:

```
void Test::formatLine(string format, ...)
{
    vector<char> buf(256);
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    vsnprintf_s(&buf[0], buf.size(), buf.size() + strlen(format.c_str()), format.c_str(), args);
    va_end(args);
    cout << &buf[0] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Only trivial types are allowed to be passed to `...`, `std::string` is no such type.

Comment: @Xeo But he is only passing trivial types in his examples :) Of course, you're right, this will fail horribly if you change the example to `t.formatLine("Hello %s!", std::string("monsieur"));`

Comment: Your "working example" is good as long as the resulting string does fit into 256 characters. Also, it is using a Microsoft-specific, non-portable `vsprintf_s` function; this might or might not be a concern for you.

Comment: Why `buf.size() + strlen(format.c_str())`? This doesn't make any sense. I suggest you pass `_TRUNCATE` as the third parameter of `vsnprintf_s`. And of course, you still have a problem if the resulting string is longer than 256 characters.

Comment: I'm trying to make the resulting string size dynamic - out of curiosity - 256 should be more than enough for me right now. The non-portable function is not a concern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, it's `buffer.c_str()` and `format.c_str()` (note the parentheses).

Second, the first parameter of `vsprintf` should be a modifiable buffer of sufficient size. You are trying to pass a `const char*` pointing to a buffer just one byte large.

You could use `vector<char>` as a buffer holder (it's easy to resize). The problem is, there's no way to get the required buffer size out of `vsprintf`. One technique is to allocate some initial buffer, then call `vsnprintf` (note the 'n') repeatedly, doubling the size of the buffer every time the function says it's too small.

Comment: Could you maybe give me an example on how to use vector<char> in this case? I just can't figure out how to use it with vsnprintf().

Comment: `vector<char> buf(1024); vsnprintf(&buf[0], buf.size(), format.c_str(), args);`. Resizing the buffer is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: @phew `vsnprintf` is the right idea, but you shouldn't have to call it repeatedly. Make `buffer` a `vector<char>` and call `vsnprint(&buffer[0], 0, format.c_str(), args);`. If the return value is non-negative, call `buffer.resize(retval+1);` and then `vsnprintf(&buffer[0], retval+1, format.c_str(), args);`

Comment: @Praetorian: Interesting. I was going by [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kt27hek.aspx), which states that `vsnprintf` returns the number of characters written if successful, and -1 when buffer is too small. I've now checked the C99 standard, which says that `vsnprintf` returns the required size of the buffer, and thus can be used to measure it in advance. I wonder (but am too lazy to check) whether MSVC implementation is non-conforming, or whether the documentation is wrong.

Comment: @phew And make sure you give the vector an initial size of at least 1, otherwise `&buffer[0]` will be undefined behavior.

Comment: @Igor Yeah that does seem non-conforming. I don't have MSVC installed on this machine (and probably would be too lazy myself to test anyway :)) to verify whether the implementation or documentation is broken.

Comment: @Praetorian: Also, per C99, the first parameter may be `NULL` if the second is 0, so one can do `vsnprint(NULL, 0, format.c_str(), args);`. This removes the concern of doing `&buf[0]` on a zero-sized vector. Also, one shouldn't pass the same `va_list` value twice to two `vsnprintf` calls; per 7.15p3, the value becomes indeterminate after the first call. One must use `va_start` again, or else make a copy with `va_copy` beforehand.

Comment: @Praetorian I'm not sure if that is a proper solution but I just EDITed the post and added a working function - is this the way to go?

Answer (score 12):

**A Production Quality Answer**

```
#include <cstdarg>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// requires at least C++11
const std::string vFormat(const std::string sFormat, ...) {

    const char * const zcFormat = sFormat.c_str();

    // initialize use of the variable argument array
    va_list vaArgs;
    va_start(vaArgs, sFormat);

    // reliably acquire the size from a copy of
    // the variable argument array
    // and a functionally reliable call
    // to mock the formatting
    va_list vaCopy;
    va_copy(vaCopy, vaArgs);
    const int iLen = std::vsnprintf(NULL, 0, zcFormat, vaCopy);
    va_end(vaCopy);

    // return a formatted string without
    // risking memory mismanagement
    // and without assuming any compiler
    // or platform specific behavior
    std::vector<char> zc(iLen + 1);
    std::vsnprintf(zc.data(), zc.size(), zcFormat, vaArgs);
    va_end(vaArgs);
    return std::string(zc.data(), zc.size()); } 

#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

// demonstration of use
int main() { 

    std::time_t t = std::time(nullptr);
    int i1 = 11; int i2 = 22; int i3 = 33;
    std::cerr
        << std::put_time(std::localtime(& t), "%D %T")
        << vFormat(" [%s]: %s {i1=%d, i2=%d, i3=%d}",
                "DEBUG",
                "Xyz failed",
                i1, i2, i3)
        << std::endl;
    return 0; }
```