# __VA_ARGS__, is this code snippet portable?

Tags: c++

Is this code snippet portable?

definition:

```
#define log(...)  std::cout << __FILE__ << "[" << __LINE__  << "]:" \
                            << string_format(__VA_ARGS__) \
                            << std::endl << std::flush
```

usage:

```
log("i = %d", i);
```

and string_format is sprintf that outputs a std::string taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/8098080/624074 It works with my gcc 4.6.3 here but I don't want to have compilation issues later with other compilers.

Comment: Port it and find out.

Comment: You are right not determine portability by empirical test. But why print log messages to `cout` and not `clog`? And `endl` already performs a flush.

Comment: what is clog? Is endl flush part of standard or compiler dependent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the macro `__VA_ARGS__` is part of standard C++:

> #### C++11 §16.3.1 Argument substitution
>
> An identifier `__VA_ARGS__`that occurs in the replacement list shall be treated as if it were a parameter, and the variable arguments shall form the preprocessing tokens used to replace it.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty portable, for the most part.  It's part of the C++11 language standard (as well as C99), so most modern compilers support it.  You might run into problems with older compilers that only support C++03.