# How to print positive numbers with a prefix + in C++

Tags: c++, int

Is there any way to print the integer along with its sign in c++...i.e. by default if the number is negative we would get a `-` sign printed. In the same way can we get `+` before the positive numbers.

```
int x=-1;
cout<<"x="<<x;
```

gives output `x=-1`

but,..

```
int x=+1;
cout<<"x="<<x;
```

gives output as `x=1` but how do i get it printed as `x=+1`

I know we can take cases by using `if-else` for x>0 and x<0;..but without using the if-else is there any direct way of printing in c++

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`std::showpos`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/showpos/):

```
int x = 1;
std::cout << "x=" << std::showpos << x;
```

Answer (score 1):

**C++20 `std::format` option `+`**

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/formatter#Standard_format_specification the following should hold:

```
#include <format>

// "1,+1,1, 1"
std::cout << std::format("{0:},{0:+},{0:-},{0: }", 1);

// "-1,-1,-1,-1"
std::cout << std::format("{0:},{0:+},{0:-},{0: }", -1);
```

The existing `fmt` library implements it for before it gets official support: https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt Install on Ubuntu 22.04:

```
sudo apt install libfmt-dev
```

Modify source to replace:

- `<format>` with `<fmt/core.h>`
- `std::format` to `fmt::format`

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include <fmt/core.h>

int main() {
    std::cout << fmt::format("{0:},{0:+},{0:-},{0: }\n", 1);
    std::cout << fmt::format("{0:},{0:+},{0:-},{0: }\n", -1);
}
```

and compile and run with:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o main.out main.cpp -lfmt
./main.out
```

Output:

```
1,+1,1, 1
-1,-1,-1,-1
```

More information at: [std::string formatting like sprintf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342162/stdstring-formatting-like-sprintf/57286312#57286312)

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
cout<<"x="<<(x>0)?"+":""<<x;
```

it's a bit clumsy, but fits the bill

Comment: Are you sure that this approach works? I got the following error `error: invalid operands of types ‘const char [1]’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator<<’`