# Preferred method for string formatting in c++?

Tags: c++, string-formatting

This is a bit verbose to my taste:

```
ostrstream ss;
ss << "Selected elements: " << i << "," << j << ".";
string msg(ss.str(), (size_t)ss.pcount());
```

Is there an elegant way to format a text message using a concise one-line statement perhaps with templates or macros?

Comment: like `printf` or `sprintf` you mean?

Comment: You could check out boost format: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/format/

Comment: yes, like sprintf but type-safe.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342162/stdstring-formatting-like-sprintf

Comment: Yes, Boost.Format is the answer.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Ugh, that question and its answers are horrible. I wish you hadn't closed this; I was _just_ about to submit a good answer with a good example for _this_ OP's specific question. *Sigh*. Oh well.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit At your service, reopened ;-) ...

Comment: Agree it is not a duplicate the way it was asked - Alex obviously wanted something else even though boost format is in that question way down the list

Comment: boost format was inspired by python I believe. enven though python 3 dropped the syntax.

Comment: If you really want a one-liner, you can do this: `string msg = (ostringstream("Selected elements: ") << i << "," << j << ".").str();` Note the use of `ostringstream` instead of `ostrstream`.

Comment: @Remy Yikes! I wouldn't call that elegant :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit _"I was just about to submit a good answer with a good example for this OP's specific question."_ ??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I went to bed.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2342162/560648 (but I'm still not convinced)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes; you are looking for [Boost.Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/format/index.html):

```
const int i = 3, j = 4;
const std::string msg = (boost::format("Selected elements: %d %d") % i % j).str();
```

([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e1154b0aed3401ef))

Answer (score -6):

What you are most likely looking for is [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) which works like printf, but returns a cstring. <del>Thus your code would be

`string msg(sprintf( "Selected elements: %d, %d.", i, j ) )`</del>

**EDIT**

Looks like I didn't read my own link. So again you have a three line code. You could always define the following

```
std::string itostr( int i )
{
    char temp[20];
    std::sprintf( temp, "%d" i);
    std::string out(temp);
    return out;
}
```

Then you can just use the + operator to concat strings.

```
string msg("Selected elements: " + itostr(i) + "," + itostr(j) + ".");
```

Comment: this cannot work. `sprintf` outputs the result in its first argument. here your first argument is the format string. which should be a constant.

Comment: _`std::sprintf()`_ is the worst recommendation I can think of here.