# Printing multiple outputs on same line

Tags: c++

there. I'm self learning C++ out of "C++ without fear". There is an exercise dealing with the GCD of 2 numbers that asks to print "GCD(a,b) =>" at each step in the proceedure. I was able to get this working:

```
int gcd (int a, int b);

int main() {
    int i,j;
    cout << "Enter the first integer" << endl;
    cin >> i;
    cout << "Enter the second integer" << endl;
    cin >> j;
    int k = gcd(i,j);
    cout << "The GCD is " << k << endl; 
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

int gcd (int a, int b){
    if(b==0){
        cout << "GCF(" << a;
        cout << "," << b;
        cout << ") => " <<endl;
        return a;
    }
    else {
        cout << "GCF(" << a;
        cout << "," << b;
        cout << ") => " << endl;
        return gcd(b,a%b);
    }
}
```

I was just wondering if there is a nicer way to go about printing each step of finding the GCD. That is, is there a "nicer" way to write this part of the code:

```
     cout << "GCF(" << a;
     cout << "," << b;
     cout << ") => " << endl;
```

? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd use `std::cout << "GCF(" << a << ',' << b << ") => \n";`.  You can just do it once before the `if`, and indeed the `if` can be replaced by `return b ? gcd(b, a % b) : a;`, which means if `b` is non-0 return `gcd(...)` otherwise `a`.

Comment: It certainly depends on what you mean by "nicer."  You can certainly just use a single `cout` and chain the outputs on a single line if you desire.

Comment: I was not aware that you could use the nested quotations in that way. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
     cout << "GCF(" << a << ',' << b << ") =>" << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not C++ but you could use the C way of printing it which in my opinion looks better in this situation because there are far fewer stream operators, `<<` in the way.

```
#include <cstdio>

printf("GCF(%d, %d) =>\n", a, b);
```

But this is a C way of doing things... You could use something like [`boost::format`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/format/) as is mentioned in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2342204/1667513).

Comment: I am familiar with the C way of doing things. Thanks a bunch for the responses, guys!

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  cout << 6+2 <<"\n" << 6-2;
}
```