# Open up text file in Notepad after it was just made

Tags: c++

I have a little program that I made which allows me to take in some text and sort it and make it look the way I want it to. One of my functions to save the new text file allows the user to input the name of the file using C++.

What I want to do is at the end of the program, I want it to open notepad displaying that new text file. I know you use " system("notepad.exe (txt file)")." But I can't add a string variable in place of the txt file. It requires the name of the text file, but the file name could be anything depending on the user.

Any help or a link to where I can read about it would be great!
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342162/stdstring-formatting-like-sprintf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assemble the command in a `std::string` and then use its `c_str` function to pass to `system`.

Comment: Downvote with no comment - nice. Nobody learns anything!

Comment: I was a little rusty with my c++(still consider myself a begginer) and was trying to figure out what you were trying to say. After testing, your method worked! Thank you so much sir for taking the time.

Comment: Btw I wasn't the one who downvoted you, but I did upvote :D