# Write a string to char while passing arguments to the string

Tags: c++, string

I have the following code:

```
char szBuf[256] = "";
std::string szFmt = "You have recieved %s item."
string szName = "Fork";
snprintf(szBuf, sizeof(szBuf), szFmt.c_str(), szName);
```

I'm trying to combine szFmt with szBuf while combining szFmt with szName according to.However, when I execute this code in win10, I getting such an weird output:

> You've received the LÃý item.

And when I try to execute the code in OSX El Capitan, I'm getting the following error

> cannot pass object of non-trivial type 'string' throgh variadic function;
>   call will about at runtime

So what is the problem, and how can I solve this?

Note: I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342162/stdstring-formatting-like-sprintf?noredirect=1&lq=1) question, but in the answer, they are passing directly "Fork", which also works in me; however it doesn't work when I pass it as szName.

Comment: The second argument to [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) should be the size of the *destination buffer*. In your case it should be `sizeof szBuf`. When you get the size of a `std::string` object, you get the actual size of the `std::string` object, not the size of the string it contains (that would be e.g. `szFmt.length()`).

Comment: You are mixing C and C++ idioms here, which is why you're having a problem. `sizeof(szFmt)` is never going to give you the length of the string; that would be `szFmt.length()`. But really, just drop `snprintf` altogether and use streams.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for pointing out, I corrected it but, as you might guess, the problems remains.

Comment: As for your problem, I recommend you look into [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) instead.

Comment: Any reason you're not just using something like: `std::string text = "You have recieved " + name + " item.";`? (name must be a `std::string`)

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks for suggestiong, but I do not have the freedom to use whatever I want in the project that I'm working with, so ı need to stick to these.

Comment: @NathanOliver Becuase in the original code, the string in szFmt retracted from a .tbl file, so I cannot do that, unless, of course, first split the string in to two and then add szName while combining again, but this is a rather ugly method.

Comment: You forgot the `.c_str()` part of `szName`.

Comment: @AndreKampling Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better solutions were mentioned in the comments (`ostringstream`) but for further educational value, I'll address the immediate problem here.

Varargs (the mechanism through which the `printf` family of functions can accept a variable number of arguments) are not as strictly type checked as the rest. In this case, `snprintf` is expecting a `char*` to the string, but you're passing `szName` which is a `string` object. So you need to call `.c_str()` on that as well:

```
snprintf(szBuf, sizeof(szBuf), szFmt.c_str(), szName.c_str());
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) will simplify things, especially since it's more type-safe than the `printf` functions inherited from C, but also since it can handle all standard types and with proper overloading of the output operator `<<` you can also use it very easily for custom classes.

The important thing to remember with `std::ostringstream` is that it is an ordinary output stream, just like `std::cout`, and if you can use `std::cout` then you can also use `std::ostringstream` (or any other standard output stream).

Now for how to use it:

```
std::ostringstream ostr;  // Define the stream object
ostr << "You have recieved " << szName << " item.";
```

And that's about it.

To access the string you use the [`str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream/str) function:

```
std::cout << "The output is " << ostr.str() << '\n';
```

And if you want to copy it into a `char` buffer for some reason:

```
// Use `strncpy` to not overflow the destination buffer
std::strncpy(szBuf, ostr.str().c_str(), sizeof szBuf - 1);

// Remember that `strncpy` might not terminate the destination, so do it explicitly
szBuf[sizeof szBuf - 1] = '\0';
```