# Function taking a variadic template pack to convert std::strings to const char *?

Tags: c++, formatting

I'm using a format function inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26221725/4154993). As long as I pass `const char*` into it, everything works just fine:

```
const char* hello = "Hello";
std::string world = "world";

string_format("%s, %s!", hello , world.c_str()); 
// Returns "Hello, world!"
```

Now, I am using std::strings everywhere and I'd like to avoid calling `.c_str()` everywhere. How can I modify this function to call it for me and to allow me to just pass std::strings into it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up using an intermediate function `safe`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <type_traits>


using namespace std;

template<typename T>
T safe(const T& value)
{return value;}

const char * safe(const string& value)
{return value.c_str();}


template<typename ... Args>
string string_format( const std::string& format, const Args& ... args )
{
    size_t size = snprintf( nullptr, 0, format.c_str(), safe(args)... ) + 1; // Extra space for '\0'
    unique_ptr<char[]> buf( new char[ size ] ); 
    snprintf( buf.get(), size, format.c_str(), safe(args)... );
    return string( buf.get(), buf.get() + size - 1 ); // We don't want the '\0' inside
}


int main()
{
    cout<<string_format("%s, %s! %d", "hello", string("world"), 42);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the `.c_str()` call to the parameter pack expansion inside the template function.

```
template<typename ... StringArgs>
std::string
string_format(const std::string& format, StringArgs ... args)
{
    std::size_t size = std::snprintf(nullptr, 0, format.c_str(), args.c_str() ...) + 1;
                                                               //^^^^^^^^^^^^
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> buf(new char[size]);
    std::snprintf(buf.get(), size, format.c_str(), args.c_str() ...);
                                                 //^^^^^^^^^^^^
    return std::string(buf.get(), buf.get() + size - 1);
}

int main(void)
{
    std::string h{"hello"};
    std::string w{"world"};
    std::cout << string_format("%s %s\n", h, w) << std::endl; // This works
    // This won't compile
    // std::cout << string_format("%d\n", 0) << std::endl;
}
```

This works because of how packs are expanded. From [the docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack):

> A pattern followed by an ellipsis, in which the name of at least one parameter pack appears at least once, is expanded into zero or more comma-separated instantiations of the pattern, where the name of the parameter pack is replaced by each of the elements from the pack, in order.

There are several examples on that page of applying various transformations to each element in the pack, by doing things like `func(pack)...`, which is  equivalent to `func(item0), func(item1), ...`.

---

An obvious downside of this modified function is that it will not compile if the parameter pack is not all `std::strings`, because the `.c_str()` method is applied to every element of the parameter pack on expansion. You could probably figure out some trickery to keep both versions around, though.

Comment: Thank you, I found a solution inspired by your answer - see mine