# C++ What should I use to save formatted in a string variable like sprintf()?

Tags: c++, string, opencv, formatting, printf

I'm used to programming in C but now I needed to use C++ for a project, and I need to save some text into a string, the code I would have used in C would have been

```
sprintf(pathFotosLimpias, "CleanPictures/Picture_T%d_%d", pictureNumber, templateNumber);
```

Or something like that, but pathFotosLimpias is a string so it doesn't work and I can't find how to save it as a sting, I think there is a boost function which does something similar to what I need but I can't figure out what exactly should I do, can someone explain what I need and maybe give me an example on how to use it?

Thank you.

Update: *It is apparently a cv::String from opencv, I'm a bit more confused now.* Nevermind, that was an error.

Comment: You cannot  really use `sprintf` with `std::strings`. Use `std::ostringstream` instead.

Comment: In response to your edit, I don't know anything about the `cv::String` type, but it is probably incompatible with use of `sprintf`. If you are wedded to using that function, then you need to output into a  C-style string (i.e. a char array) and then convert that to the type you need. But tjis is not exactly optimal.

Comment: Maybe you can use something like `std::stringstream`. You can use then the operator `<<` to load arbitray content in the stream. Then call the method `str()` to retrieve the string.

Comment: I looked it up and yes, that seems to be what i want, but i'm having a hard time understanding how it works. Should `pathFotosLimpias << "CleanPictures/Picture_T" << pictureNumber << templateNumber ` work? Do you have any link to somewhere where I could learn how to use it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342162/stdstring-formatting-like-sprintf

Answer (score 2):

You can either directly add strings:

```
#include <string> //put this at the top
auto path = std::string("CleanPictures/Picture_T") + std::to_string(pictureNumber) + "_" + std::to_string(templateNumber);
```

(Here the `"_"` is implicitly converted to `std::string`)

Or use stringstreams:

```
#include <sstream> //put this at the top
auto stream = std::stringstream{};
stream << "CleanPictures/Picture_T" << pictureNumber << '_' << templateNumber;
auto path = stream.str(); //get the string from the stream
```

Another possibility would be to use [abseil](https://abseil.io/), which provides a type safe replacement for `printf`:

```
auto path = absl::StrFormat("CleanPictures/Picture_T%d_%d", pictureNumber, templateNumber);
```

From all these possibilities I would recommend:

1. Use stringstreams if you are concerned about type safety.
2. Use `std::to_string` if you want some more performant code.
3. Use **abseil** if you are concerned about type safety and performance.

**EDIT:**

Another possibility for generating strings is the [fmt](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) library. I would put it at the top of my recommendations now, as it provides a wide range of formatting options (using the python formatting style) and is easy to read/use.

```
#include <fmt/format.h>
std::string path = fmt::format("CleanPictures/Picture_T{:d}_{:d}", pictureNumber, templateNumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`std::sprintf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) in C++, similar to how you use `sprintf()` in C:

```
#include <cstdio>

char pathFotosLimpias[...];
std::sprintf(pathFotosLimpias, "CleanPictures/Picture_T%d_%d", pictureNumber, templateNumber);
```

However, you should use [`std::ostringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) in C++ instead:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::ostringstream oss;
oss << "CleanPictures/Picture_T" << pictureNumber << "_" << templateNumber;
std::string pathFotosLimpias = oss.str();
```