# How to use the <format> header

Tags: c++, formatting, g++, header-files, c++20

In a related question ("*[std::string formatting like sprintf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342162/stdstring-formatting-like-sprintf)*") I learned about this awesome new C++20 header [<format>](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format).

However, [there seems to be no supporting compiler](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#C.2B.2B20_library_features). Is this correct or is there a way to use it anyway?
I'm using g++ 9.3 with the `-std=c++2a` flag and the library `<format>` is not recognised.

```
#include <format> // fatal error: format: No such file or directory
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout << std::format("Hello {}!", "World");
}
```

`g++-9 test.cpp -o test -std=c++2a`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [`libfmt`](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt). The `<format>` header is essentially a standardized libfmt (with a few small features removed, if I remember correctly).

Comment: "*The <format> header is heavily inspired by it.*" No, that's project is [touted as](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0645r10.html) a"full *implementation*" of the library.

Comment: @NicolBolas I could be wrong, but doesn't libfmt predate the `<format>` proposal?

Comment: It may have predated the proposal, but it seems to have tracked the proposal's development. Since, you know, the proposal and library are written by the same person;)

Comment: @NicolBolas Oh. I'll change the wording.

Comment: Thanks, I made it work with the following steps: 1. Clone repo, make build subdir, `cmake ..` (with options you want) and `make` as usual. 2. Either `make install` to your system, or add include path, lib path and lib linking to your C++ project config. 3. Replace `#include <format>"` with `#include <fmt/format.h>` (or `"fmt/format.h"` if you don't consider it system header). 4. Replace all `std::(format function)` with `fmt::(format function)`. If you want agnostic code that won't change when <format> is added to std, you'll need a proxy...

Answer (score 7):

**MSVC** and **Clang** are the only 2 compilers supporting the  header. **GCC** only added support in 2023.

You can find the latest support matrix [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support).

| C++20 feature | GCC libstdc++ | Clang libc++ | MSVC STL | Apple Clang* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Text formatting | 13 | 14* 17 | 19.29 (16.10)* | None |

Comment: This cleared up a lot of confusion and settings headaches, thanks. Should be included in top answers

Comment: @Scrapper142 I updated it with the latest information

Answer (score 5):

You can use `fmt::format` as a polyfill for `std::format`.
There is a `libfmt-dev` package available on debian/ubuntu.
Differences between `std::format` and `fmt::format` are [described here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/format-in-visual-studio-2019-version-16-10/#differences-from-fmt-not-exhaustive)

**EDIT: simpler polyfill**

Drop in header replacement:

```
#ifndef __cpp_lib_format
  // std::format polyfill using fmtlib
  #include <fmt/core.h>
  namespace std {
  using fmt::format;
  }
#else
  #include <format>
#endif
```

CMake automatic feature detection:

```
include(CheckIncludeFileCXX)
check_include_file_cxx("format" CXX_FORMAT_SUPPORT)
if (NOT CXX_FORMAT_SUPPORT)
    find_package(fmt REQUIRED)
endif()

if (NOT CXX_FORMAT_SUPPORT)
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} fmt::fmt)
endif()
```

**Previous polyfill**

I currently use this header as a replacement for the `format` header:

```
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>

namespace std
{
   template<typename... Args>
   inline auto format(Args&&... args) -> decltype(fmt::v7::format(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
   {
      return fmt::v7::format(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this library is already  mentioned in the other answer

Comment: With this header, the fmtlib is a a droppin replacement for std::format: you can switch between std::format and fmt::format without modifying your code.