# Where does Homebrew install C++ packages?

Tags: c++, macos, homebrew

I would like to use C++'s `std::format` library to format strings. See the minimal working example below.

```cpp
/* example.cpp */
#include <iostream>
#include <format>
#include <string>

int main() {
   std::string s = std::format("Hello, {}!", "John");
   std::cout << s << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

However, when I compile my code, I get the following error message:

```sh
example.cpp:2:10: fatal error: format: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <format>
```

I am using the latest version of macOS, and I have Homebrew installed as my package manager. I already installed `clang-format` through Homebrew, but for some reason, my compiler can't locate the header file. Can somebody help me figure out the problem is? I have tried using Apple's GCC and the custom GCC10 provided by Homebrew, but in both cases, I get the same error message. Is this a Homebrew issue or a C++ issue?

Comment: What command do you use to compile?

Comment: FYI `clang-format` is a code formatting CLI tool, and is not related to `<format>`/`std::format`. The status of format support in libc++ is listed as "in progress" at https://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/Cxx2aStatus.html, so I'm not sure if it is available (if so, possibly under the `experimental` namespace). In the meantime you can use [`fmt`](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) instead.

Comment: It looks like this is part of C++ 20. Is that even available on your Mac yet?

Comment: Yes, at a minimum you would need to use something like `-std=c++2a` for this to work.

Comment: @jtbandes Is the only one with correct/helpful information so far. And I'm not sure anything else needs to be said.

Comment: @JosephLarson I am using the following command to compile: `g++-10 -Wall -std=c++11 example.cpp -o example`. I have also tried using Apple's Clang version of GCC, but I still get an error message saying that the header file can't be found. Could this be a Homebrew issue?

Answer (score -2):

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61441669/4116538) to use fmt, you can install the library with `brew install fmt`, then modified the code to

```cpp
/* example.cpp */
#include "fmt/format.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
   std::string s = fmt::format("Hello, {}!", "John");
   std::cout << s << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

and compile with

```sh
clang++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -lfmt
```

Comment: Don't repeat answers, flag as duplicate and move on. The C++20 flag is not needed, and neither is the v7 namespace. If you brew installed fmt, indicating a local header is subjectively less than ideal was well.

Comment: The answer indicated to use `fmt` and I demonstrated the way to make it work on a Mac. The code won't compile without the c++20 flag. The namespace is a good point though, thank you!

Comment: That's a lie. I use fmt on a mac, and have never compiled to C++20.

Comment: Oh yes actually the c++11 would be enough. Thank you