# How can I format a collection as a string efficiently in C++?

Tags: c++, string-formatting, stdvector, stdstring, fmt

I have a program that has a string (which will need to be formatted) and takes a collection of elements from an external source.
The string must be formatted using the elements of the collection, which are std::string.
I can't formatting the string manually, such as:

```
// Just examples
sprintf(test, "%s this is my %s. This is a number: %d.", var[0], var[1], etc..);        // i can't do this
fmt::printf("%s this is my %s. This is a number: %d.", var[0], var[1], etc..);          // i can't do this (i also have fmt library)
```

This because the number of elements in the collection is variable.
What i would like to do is formatting the string as efficiently as possible.

This is the code:

```
std::string test = "%s this is my %s. This is a number: %d.";
std::vector<std::string> vec;

vec.push_back("Hello");
vec.push_back("string");
vec.push_back("5");


// String Formatting
std::size_t found;
for (auto i : vec)
{
    found = test.find("%");
    if (found != std::string::npos)
    {
        test.erase(found, 2);
        test.insert(found, i);
    }
}

std::cout << test;
```

Note1: I used a std::vector to manage the elements of the collection, but i could use any other structure.

That's why i didn't put the definitions in the code.
In addition, the code i wrote isn't work in case i have a string with a percentage, such as:

```
std::string test = "%s this is a percentage: %d%%. This is a number: %d.";
// Output = "Hello this is a percentage: string5. This is a number: %d."
```

In conclusion:
What is the most efficient way to formatting the string with multiple elements?
Even without using a vector, but using another structure. Or using fmt or boost? (maybe boost decreases efficiency)
My development environment is Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Note that VS2019 only supports C++14,17 and 20.  There is no flag you can use to force it into C++11 mode.

Comment: `getArgument(&str[0])` likely corrupts `str` and memory, because `str` has 0 size and capacity, so that it cannot be possibly written into.

Comment: Like i said, getArgument and checkArguments isn't important. I add it to code only for clarity.

Comment: @Anyone97 They are important. Post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin just comment it, and insert elements manually as in the example. (vec.push_back("Hello"); etc). It's the same.

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/join.html

Comment: Perhaps this may be useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342162/stdstring-formatting-like-sprintf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using {fmt}'s recently added `dynamic_format_arg_store` (https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/releases/tag/6.2.0):

```
#include <fmt/format.h>

int main() {
  fmt::dynamic_format_arg_store<fmt::format_context> args;
  args.push_back("Hello");
  args.push_back("string");
  args.push_back("5");
  fmt::vprint("{} this is my {}. This is a number: {}.", args);
}
```

This prints (https://godbolt.org/z/jUbbUi):

```
Hello this is my string. This is a number: 5.
```

Note that {fmt} uses `{}` instead of `%` for replacement fields.