# Using sprintf without a buffer variable

Tags: c++

Is there a way to use `sprintf()` without a predefined variable?

Instead of:

```
char buffer[80];
sprintf(buffer, "%d",i );
myfunc(buffer);
```

I'd like to use:

```
myfunc(stringformat("%d",i));
```

Writing `C++`, mean C-like functions without OOP.

Comment: "Is there a way to use sprintf without a predefined variable?" - No. That's what you get for writing C in C++.

Comment: In standard C++ you can use `stringstream`, but it won't be the same.  Microsoft's `CString` class provides a `Format` function that does what you want.

Comment: `std::to_string` also does what you want (in this case).

Comment: Boost's [format library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/format/doc/format.html) also does something similar.

Comment: Not out of the box, but you can roll your own, see for example [std::string formatting like sprintf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342162/stdstring-formatting-like-sprintf).

Answer (score 0):

Do you necessarily need to use same formatting rules as in `printf/sprintf`? If so there is no standard library function to do that and you'll need to probably write your own using `snprint` under the hood (in edge cases for large format strings you would probably need to iterate over increasingly large buffer sizes or just limit maximum supported size of the output).

If you need something similar, but with different formatting - earliest it appears in standard library is C++20: [std::format](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format). There are also alternatives to standard library e.g. [boost::format](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/format/doc/format.html), [folly::sformat](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/docs/Format.md).

Also in many cases using `stringstream` is more convenient.