# Arduino -- How do I combine both string and array in a string variable

Tags: arduino

How do I combine both string and array in a string variable in Arduino's C/C++ dialect? I tried to run below lines but doesnt work.

```
int j = 0;
String value1[] = {0,1,2,3};

String httpRequestData = "&value1=" + value1[i] + "";
//then number of j++
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [std::string formatting like sprintf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342162/stdstring-formatting-like-sprintf)

Comment: Can you give detail, `doesnt work` is not very clear.

Comment: you could try CStringBuilder from my StreamLib

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your string before concatenate different types.

More details here https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringAdditionOperator

```
int j = 0;
int value1[] = {0,1,2,3};

String httpRequestData = String("&value1=");
httpRequestData += value1[i];
```

Comment: `"&value1=" + value1[i]` doesn't do what you think it does and it is wrong.

Comment: @bolov ,  I read the document of String in Arduino doc. I found that the String class has the capability to manage also integers. I've searched for String because I said that is not correct to use `sprintf(buff,"%d",value[i])` ... but now I cannot try if my concern is true! Elsewhere I think the correct way should be: `sprintf(buff,"%d",value[i].toInt())`

Comment: @bolov what this will do ? According to the Arduino doc this will concatenate.
From the doc:   `stringThree =  stringOne + 123;`

Comment: @Ôrel `"&value1="` is a C string literal and `value[i]` is `int`. Maybe `int value1[]` is a typo in your answer.

Comment: @bolov this is not a typo, as httpRequestData is a String, the magic of C++ will to the conversion and convert then concatenate the both as `String` not a `char *` and an `int`, check the shared link.
Not saying this is clean, but this is the arduino way to do

Comment: @Ôrel incorrect. `"&value1=" + value1[i]` is evaluated as a standalone sub-expression and is doing pointer arithmetics.

Comment: ok I update it to build a String and then append