# Width and setfill('-') in cpp

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and am wondering if there is a more elegant way to print out the following:

```
Celsius  Kelvin  Fahrenheit  Reaumur
-------------------------------------
```

I guess you could just do

```
cout << "Celsius  Kelvin  Fahrenheit  Reaumur" << endl << "-------------------------------------";
```

But it doesn't look good. In Ada you could do `"Width"`. Is there a similiar operator in cpp? And can you not just do `setfill('-')` and the amount of '-' you want to print out?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: There is a constructor for `std::string` that allows you to create a string of repeated single characters.  You could use that.

Comment: include <iomanip>, and you can `cout << setw(5) << setfill('-') << "" << endl;`

Comment: BTW, use `'\n'` instead of `std::endl` to output a newline. The latter is only useful for flushing the buffer afterwards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are two other ways to produce this line:

```
    std::cout << "-------------------------------------\n";
```

[`std::setfill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill) + [`std::setw`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw):

```
#include <iomanip>

    std::cout << std::setfill('-') << std::setw(38) << '\n';
```

Using a `std::string`:

```
#include <string>

    std::cout << std::string(37, '-') << '\n';
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9Ycf49s6r)

Comment: Thank you! Do you mind telling me that '\n'; does? If it's a new line then why can't we just type endl; instead

Comment: @leun You're welcome! Yes that's a newline and it's the preferred way unless you need to flush `stdout` (which `std::endl` does). Flushing comes with a cost and is rarely needed.

Answer (score 3):

You could (and probably should) use `std::format`.  Also see the `fmtlib/fmt` library:

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format
- https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/std-format-in-c-20
- https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt

Both format and fmtlib use the format spec':

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format

Also see this question which features several related answers:

- [std::string formatting like sprintf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342162/stdstring-formatting-like-sprintf)

---

You can tweak this very easily to make this fit your needs (I made some deliberate imperfections for the sake of clarity):

```
#include <fmt/core.h>

int main() {
    int const width = 12;

    // See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format
    // ^ centres the field (with default space fill)
    // -^ centres the field with "-" fill
    // 12 and 52 are specific field widths.
    // inner {} means the field width is provided by the next parameter

    fmt::print("_{:^{}} {:^{}} {:^{}} {:^12}_\n-{:-^52}\n", 
            "Celsius", width,
            "Kelvin", width,
            "Farenheit", width,
            "Reaumur",
            "=");
}
```

Output:

```
_  Celsius       Kelvin     Farenheit     Reaumur   _
--------------------------=--------------------------
```

FmtLib Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/463xWvx5P

Format Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/MP9sac7ba  (thanks Ted)

Comment: [Here's the above demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MP9sac7ba) using `std::format` too.

Comment: @TedLyngmo thanks IOU a beer :)

Comment: :-) Thank you for showing me a little about the new formatting capabilities. I'm a total rookie when it comes to those.

Answer (score 1):

Big fan of separating this out for re-use and easier reading. Example:

```cpp
std::ostream & draw_heading(std::ostream & out,
                            const std::string & heading)
{
    char old_fill = out.fill('-');
    std::streamsize old_width = out.width();
    out << h.mHeading << '\n'
        << std::setw(h.mHeading.size() + 1) << '\n';
    out.width(old_width);
    out.fill(old_fill);
    return out;
}
```

Only does the writing and will write to any output stream. It returns a reference to the stream so it can be easily tested for success or chained.

Basic Usage:

```cpp
draw_heading(std::cout, "Celsius  Kelvin  Fahrenheit  Reaumur");
```

The ugly stuff is now buried away from the main logic, which can get on with whatever the heck its job is.

Comment: The problem, of course, is that this magically changes the stream's fill character for unsuspecting users.

Comment: @Dúthomhas Woo. Hadn't thought of that and never had the problem. Probably because where it mattered I'd be setting the fill to `'0'` ahead of the numbers that followed or reflexively resetting the fill to space. I'll need to rethink a few helper functions I've dropped into my code.

Comment: `char ch = out.fill(); streamsize w = out.width(); out << ... << std::setfill(...) << std::setw(...) << ...; out.fill(ch); out.width(w);` Alternatively: `out << ...; char ch = out.fill(...); streamsize w = out.width(...); out << ...; out.fill(ch); out.width(w);`

Comment: This exercise lead me to wondering if there's a good way [to do this](https://godbolt.org/z/aEnEhezKo) without the superfluous `string`.

Comment: Duh. `std::string_view`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the literal string feature:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << R"(
This is a line of text with an underline
----------------------------------------
)";

}
```

This allows you to add all the explicit characters you want (including newline) which makes the layout of large chunks of text nicer (relatively) to do in code.

I just wish that the `R"(`   ignored the first newline if it is the only character on that line. But it still looks better than:

```
cout << "Celsius  Kelvin  Fahrenheit  Reaumur\n"
     << "------------------------------------\n";
```

or

```
cout << "Celsius  Kelvin  Fahrenheit  Reaumur\n"
     << std::string(38, '-') << "\n";
```