# prepending number with 0's

Tags: c++, formatting, iostream, setw, iomanip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Print leading zeros with C++ output operator (printf equivalent)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530614/print-leading-zeros-with-c-output-operator-printf-equivalent)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
int main()
{
   int n = 16;
   std::cout << ???(5) << n << std::endl;
}
```

I want the output to be `00016`
`setw()` prepends with spaces. Isn't it configurable what characters to prepend with `setw()`?

My eventual goal is to print a hex 2-byte number in 4 positions. Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
int main()
{
    unsigned short n = 0xA7;
    std::cout << std::hex << ???(4) << n << std::endl;
}
```

and I am expecting to get this output: `00A7`

Comment: @paxdiablo: Yeah, you are right, it's a duplicate. Sorry, voting to close

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also need `setfill('0')`.

Comment: thanks! and `???` will be `setw()`