# Printing leading spaces and zeros in C/C++

Tags: c, printf

I need to print some leading spaces and zeros before a number, so that the output will be like this:

```
00015
   22
00111
    8
  126
```

here, I need to print `leading spaces` when the number is `even` and `leading zero` when `odd`

Here's how I did it :

```
int i, digit, width=5, x=15;

if(x%2==0)  // number even
{
    digit=log10(x)+1;  // number of digit in the number
    for(i=digit ; i<width ; i++)
      printf(" ");
    printf("%d\n",x);
}
else       // number odd
{
    digit=log10(x)+1;  // number of digit in the number
    for(i=digit ; i<width ; i++)
      printf("0");
    printf("%d\n",x);
}
```

Is there any shortcut way to do this ?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530614/print-leading-zeros-with-c-output-operator

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To print `leading space and zero` you can  use this :

```
int x = 119, width = 5;

// Leading Space
printf("%*d\n",width,x);

// Leading Zero
printf("%0*d\n",width,x);
```

So in your program just change this :

```
int i, digit, width=5, x=15;

if(x%2==0)  // number even
    printf("%*d\n",width,x);
else        // number odd
    printf("%0*d\n",width,x);
```