# converting an int to a string in Objective-C while preserving '0'

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to convert an int to a string in objective-C.

I read the other questions on SO about converting ints to strings, and I tried this method in my code:

```
-(void)setCounter:(int)count
{
    counterText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",count];
}
```

However, if I want to display a number like '01' the 0 is taken out of the conversion and only '1' is displayed. Is there a workaround?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing leading 0's in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153890/printing-leading-0s-in-c)

Comment: Not 100%, since `stringWithFormat:` doesn't exist in C, and `sprintf` answer would produce a wrong type (although the format spec is the same).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no such number as `01`. If you write

```
int count = 01;
```

it is compiled equivalently to

```
int count = 1;
```

In fact, be careful: `07` is equivalent to `7`, but [`011` is equivalent to `9`](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/hexoctal.html)!

What you can do is ask `stringWithFormat:` to give you the zero-padding:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d",count]
```

should give you `"02"` if `count` is 2. To deconstruct it:

```
% - interpolate the next value here
0 - pad it to the width by placing zeroes on the left side
2 - width is 2 characters
d - it will be an integer. Do it now.
```

Comment: Lucky you didn't use the example: `int count = 08;` :-)

Comment: I see... Do you know of a way to get 01 to display then, without using an int? 

What I am trying to do is create a flip card counter display, and I need a way to pass it numbers to display

Comment: @Karuna-bdc: Yes, it's called using strings. Although if its' a flip card counter, it sounds like it'll always want to display 2 digits, and Amadan's already shown you how to do that.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Haha... Yeah, I remembered to put it in!

Comment: @Amadan, my lousy internet connection lopped off the second part of your answer, but I got it now. Works perfectly and thanks for the explanation

Comment: @Karuna-bdc: Probably not your fault. I'll often write a very short answer, then think "oh, I could add this", or "hmm, I wonder if it's understandable enough", and go back to add more details.

Comment: Amadan, just one idea for improvement. I'm not entirely certain ObjC is the same as C printf, but the width specifier is the _minimum_ width: printf "%02d" on 12345 will still give you 12345.

Comment: @paxdiablo: ObjC `[s]printf` is the same as the C `[s]printf`, but `sprintf` prints into a `char[]`, while presumably the OP's `counterText.text = ...` requires an ObjC `String` (which can be obtained by `[NSString stringWithCString:... encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` or by `[NSString stringWithFormat:...]`. You are, of course, correct about overflows.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a different format to the one shown, use it:

```
counterText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d",count];
```

There are a *huge* range of possibilities with the format string.

Answer (score 0):

if any number start from 0 then Its a octal representation (0 - 7). you can add zero explictly using below line.

```
  counterText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%d",count];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out..

NSNumber +numberWithInt

and then:
NSNumberFormatter -setMinimumIntegerDigits

and then get the string representation with:
NSString -stringFromNumber