# Using with atoi() in C

Tags: c, atoi

I'm trying to use `atoi()` but I need the `0` in the front, but the function ignores it

```
  sprintf(str, "%d%d%d%d",comp[cont][0],comp[cont][1],comp[cont][2],comp[cont][3]);
  conv=atoi(str);  

  printf("%d \n",conv);
```

When I print str: `0100`
And conv: `100`
Is there any way to show the `0`?

Comment: You can try using `printf` with a leading zero.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153890/printing-leading-0s-in-c

Comment: The leading zero is not part of the *value*, it's part of the *representation*.

Comment: In C a leading `0` indicates the octal representation of an integer value: `020==0x10=16`. Binary valued I'd prefix with a `0b`.

Comment: `str` has a leading 0 if and only if `comp[cont][0]` is 0, so you want to print `conv` with a leading 0 if and only if `comp[cont][0]` was 0 at the time `str` was created but you do not want to output `str` itself? And, if yes, why?

Comment: str is a char, I needed it to concatenate the 4 int, them using atoi() I converted it into an int again because I need to convert the binary to decimal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because integers simply doesn't *have* zeros in front of them.

You need to print it with that:

```
printf("%04d \n",conv);
```

You might find e.g. [this `printf` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) useful.

Comment: I know they dont, but it's a binary number and I need the zero to convert it to decimal and write it on a txt. It worked, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just change the printf format:

```
printf("%04d \n",conv);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just append the zero while printing. Try the following

```
print("0%d\n", conv);
```

Comment: It will fail when you have 0010

Comment: It mentions: "but I need the 0 in the front". It does not mention number of zero and the length of the number (number of digits).

Comment: It'd worked but I need the zero to convert the binary number. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated and not just do directly:

```
printf("%d%d%d%d", comp[cont][0], comp[cont][1], comp[cont][2], comp[cont][3]);
```

Comment: Because it's a binary number and I need to concatenate it and convert to decimal