# Printing leading 0's dynamically at run time in C

Tags: c

I need to print some leading 0's before a number dynamically at run-time.
Here's what i did :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int leading_zero, n;
    scanf("%d %d",&leading_zero, &n);
    for(int i=0; i<leading_zero; i++)
      printf("0");
    printf("%d\n",n);
return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to do this without loop?

I searched over internet and i found something like this -> `printf("%05d\n",n)`
which will print `static` number of leading 0's

Is there any way to do this at run-time?

Comment: The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23167000/694576

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to print `0` before a number dynamically at runtime you can do one of these :

```
printf("%0*d\n", leading_zero, n);
```

or

```
printf("%.*d\n", leading_zero, n);
```