# How do I make scanf() scan in integers one digit at a time?

Tags: c, scanf

I want to scan in a date in the form of mm/dd, so I've written this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  int start_date[4];

  scanf("%d%d/%d%d", &start_date[0], &start_date[1], &start_date[2], &start_date[3]);

  printf("%d%d%d%d\n", start_date[0], start_date[1], start_date[2], start_date[3]);

  return 0;
}
```

But when I enter the following for example:

```
04/20
```

`scanf()` reads this

```
4-419644000
```

How do I make it so that when I print out each element in `start_date`, I get this:

```
0420
```

when I enter the input from earlier?

Comment: I would use a loop to test each character to determine whether it's numeric, then combine the digits to  string.  Right now, scanf isn't parsing the / correctly.

Answer (score 7):

#### Reading one digit at a time

Use `%1d`:

```
int n = scanf("%1d%1d/%1d%1d", &start_date[0], &start_date[1], &start_date[2], &start_date[3]);
if (n != 4) { …handle error… }
```

Note that this will accept both:

```
19/96
```

and

```
1 9/
9

6
```

as valid inputs.  If you need the digits to be contiguous, you have to work harder.  In general, it is usually best to read a line with [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) (or POSIX's
[`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html)) and then parse the line with [`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html).  You can also consider checking the length of the string, etc.

#### What went wrong?

Incidentally, you said:

> But when I enter the following for example:
>
> ```
> 04/20
> ```
>
> `scanf()` reads this
>
> 4-419644000

What happens here is that the `04` is read by the first `%d`; the second `%d` fails because `/` doesn't match a number, so nothing is written to `&start_date[1]` (or the other two items), and `scanf()` returns 1.  Since you didn't check the return value, you weren't aware of the problem.  Note that the check should be as I showed (`n != 4` where 4 is the number of items you expect to be converted).  Checking for EOF would not work correctly; there wasn't an EOF on the file, but there was a conversion failure.  Since you printed an uninitialized variable, the value you got was indeterminate ('undefined behaviour' in the jargon); a largish negative number is reasonable (as is any other value whatsoever, or a crash, or …).  In fact, you have three indeterminate numbers smushed together, of which only the first is negative.  Avoid undefined behaviour; always check that your input operations succeed — and don't use the results if they fail.  (Or, at least, be very cautious about using the results if they fail; you need to be sure you know what's going on.)

Answer (score 4):

The `%d` would consume the string "04", if you want to input digit by digit really, try `%c`, then adjust them to digit:

```
char start_data[4];
scanf("%c%c/%c%c", &start_date[0], &start_date[1], &start_date[2], &start_date[3]);
start_data[0] -= '0';
start_data[1] -= '0';
start_data[2] -= '0';
start_data[3] -= '0';
```

Another way, you can just input mm and dd and do arithmetic on it:

```
int mm, dd;
scanf("%d/%d", &mm, &dd);
int m0 = mm % 10;
int m1 = mm / 10;
int d0 = dd % 10;
int d1 = dd / 10;
```

Comment: Note that using `%c` would store values in the range 48..57 (assuming a code set based on ASCII such as ISO 8859-15 or UTF-8), not values in the range 0..9.

Answer (score 2):

Change the data type to char[], so your code look like this

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main (void)
 {
    char start_date[4];

    scanf("%c%c/%c%c", &start_date[0], &start_date[1], &start_date[2], &start_date[3]);

    printf("%c%c%c%c\n", start_date[0], start_date[1], start_date[2], start_date[3]);

    return 0;
 }
```

If you want to change the data type of each characters to integers you can change by look into the ASCII code then substract the characters with ASCII '0'

Comment: Note that using `%c` would store values in the range 48..57 (assuming a code set based on ASCII such as ISO 8859-15 or UTF-8), not values in the range 0..9.

Comment: Yes, of course. So I leave a note that must change in accordance with the ASCII code. by reducing the value of each of the characters with ASCII '0'

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use [`strptime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strptime.html) instead.  It's purpose-built for parsing standard date formats such as yours.  Just read the entire "word" as a string and feed it to `strptime()`.

Answer (score 1):

This was too long for a comment, but you can see why this is happening here:

```
   0x080484a7 <+58>:    call   0x8048360 <__isoc99_scanf@plt>
   0x080484ac <+63>:    mov    0x2c(%esp),%ebx
   0x080484b0 <+67>:    mov    0x28(%esp),%ecx
   0x080484b4 <+71>:    mov    0x24(%esp),%edx
   0x080484b8 <+75>:    mov    0x20(%esp),%eax
   0x080484bc <+79>:    mov    %ebx,0x10(%esp)
   ...
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) break *main+79
Breakpoint 4 at 0x80484bc
(gdb) r
Starting program: /root/test/testcode
04/21
Breakpoint 4, 0x080484bc in main ()
(gdb) i r
eax            0x4      4
ecx            0x80484fb        134513915
edx            0xb7fff000       -1207963648
ebx            0xb7fcc000       -1208172544
esp            0xbffff720       0xbffff720
ebp            0xbffff758       0xbffff758
esi            0x0      0
edi            0x0      0
eip            0x80484bc        0x80484bc <main+79>
eflags         0x286    [ PF SF IF ]
cs             0x73     115
ss             0x7b     123
ds             0x7b     123
es             0x7b     123
fs             0x0      0
gs             0x33     51
(gdb) c
Continuing.

4-1207963648134513915-1208172544
```

Here's whats happening:

```
mov    0x2c(%esp),%ebx
mov    0x28(%esp),%ecx
mov    0x24(%esp),%edx
mov    0x20(%esp),%eax
```

These four `mov` statements are preparation for the `printf()` call. Each `%d` corresponds to one of the registers: `eax ebx ecx edx`
You can see that it is moving four bytes into each register. This is the reason you see gibberish. Each `%d` getting printed is expecting a 4-byte integer.

I set a breakpoint after all four of those `mov` statements, so lets look at what they contain:

```
eax            0x4              4
ecx            0x80484fb        134513915
edx            0xb7fff000       -1207963648
ebx            0xb7fcc000       -1208172544
```

This doesn't look right at all, but it does indeed correspond to what's on the stack:

```
0xbffff740:     0x00000004      0xb7fff000      0x080484fb      0xb7fcc000
```

These are the four values that wind up in the registers.
The first one is actually your `04` combined. It interpreted `04` as being within the bounds of `%d`, which is a 4-byte integer on my machine.
Since you tried to grab four `%d`'s, the program continues as it should and prints out four `%d`s. In other words, it prints out four 4-byte integers.

The reason this is happening is what [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) explained: scanf is gobbling up the `04` into the first `%d`, then breaking on the `/`
You still have a printf() of `%d%d%d%d` though, so the program dutifully prints out the remaining 4-byte decimal values. Since `scanf` failed, the remaining 3 `%d`s contain whatever happened to be on the stack.

Comment: Well done for trying to answer what went wrong.  I'm not sure your explanation is all that comprehensible, or that delving into assembler is necessary.  As I note in an update to my answer, the problem is simply that the first `%d` reads the `04`, the second `%d` fails because `/` is not a number, and therefore none of the other three variables is set by `scanf()` and hence 3 uninitialized values are printed, the first of which happens to be negative.  The code ignores the status from `scanf()` so it is unaware that `scanf()` reported its troubles.

Comment: I am not familiar with how scanf() works and I didnt want to step through it. Failing on the `/` makes sense why the rest of the `mov`'s are failing though.

I hoped my edit would have cleared up what is being printed, Ill attempt to make it even more readable

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have another reason for using an array to store the individual digits, I suggest you just store the month and day as variables.

Also, because you know that there is a separator, accomodate it in your code. It is simpler.

This is the code you are looking for.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  int month, day;
  char sep;

  scanf("%d%c%d", &month, &sep, &day);

  printf("%d of %d\n", day, month);
  
  return 0;
}
```

Explanation for the printing ([Printing leading 0's in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153890/printing-leading-0s-in-c)):

The 0 indicates what you are padding with and the 5 shows the width of the integer number.

Example 1: If you use "%02d" (useful for dates) this would only pad zeros for numbers in the ones column. E.g., 06 instead of 6.

Example 2: "%03d" would pad 2 zeros for one number in the ones column and pad 1 zero for a number in the tens column. E.g., number 7 padded to 007 and number 17 padded to 017.

You could have also taken the data in as a string using %5s and further extract that data from the array of characters (string). Here is a good resource with examples. -> https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

I do feel that for your solution it would still have been an overkill, so I beleive the example code provided above is sufficient.