# How to convert an integer to string with leading zeros in C?

Tags: c

How can I convert an `integer` to a `string` in C and include a leading zero if the integer has only one digit? **The result is needed to print to an LCD Display and not to print to console**.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    int i = 7;
    char buffer[10];
    itoa(buffer, i, 10);
    printf ("decimal: %s\n",buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

This code would print `7` but i need it to be `07`.
But numbers greater than 10 eg.: `77` should remain the same.

Comment: You need to add a conditional if statement that detects if the integer being parsed is less than "10", and greater than 0, I assume.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing leading 0's in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153890/printing-leading-0s-in-c)

Comment: @kaylum he is asking about a string, not an integer conversion.

Comment: The reference post uses `printf` to print to stdout. If you want it to a buffer use `snprintf` but the format string is the same.

Comment: I need the string to send it to an LCD Display as descriped above. I don't want to print it to console i only do this for testing.

Comment: `snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%02d", i)`

Comment: Using `sprintf` or `snprintf` doesn't require printing to any output device. It writes to the *same* string that you use in the `itoa` call.

Comment: @AdrianMole I didn't know that, thanks then I'll test that

Comment: you have to check integer input before convert it into string and if integer is smaller than 10 use strcat to concat 0 to your string number  ?

Comment: `printf` has a large overhead due to the overwhelming amount of format specifiers and their variantes. I like the minimalistic approach using `itoa`/`ltoa`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `itoa`, you can use the `sprintf` function with a format specifier of `%02d` to force the inclusion of a leading zero:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 7;
    char buffer[10];
//  itoa(buffer, i, 10);
    sprintf(buffer, "%02d", i);
    printf("decimal: %s\n", buffer);
    return 0;
}
```