# Is there a method to see 4 algarisms before the comma?

Tags: c, numbers, printf

I know that if you do

```
printf("Number: %.2f", 1.2345);
```

The result will be "1.23"

But i'm doing a calculator of big number's, for this project I separe the number in nodes
Like (exemple)
123456789
[ 1 ] [ 2345 ] [ 6789 ]

and when I the number is: 100056789 for example
I have
[ 1 ] [ 0005 ] [ 6789 ]

But when I print I get
[ 1 ] [ 5 ] [ 6789 ]

There is a method to see the other 0's before the comma whithout transfer all to a string?
like "0005" (string) and print the string?
There is a better way of doing that?

Comment: Try %04d but it will not work if you have variable length numbers.  It will only work if the numbers always have 9 digits.

Comment: Representing big numbers in base-10 is not very compute-efficient. Usually, we want to use a power of 2 that fits in some number of bytes that is also a power of 2 (8, 16, 32, 64 bits). Then, the math happens in base-2 and you convert the result to base-10 for display. It can be a fallacy to design your internal data representation primarily for convenience of I/O. Not always, but usually.

Comment: I guess this is a duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153890/printing-leading-0s-in-c#153895

Comment: Agreed @paddy, but bignum FP representations for an interactive application may just be one of those things where it makes sense to design around I/O.  I have written an implementation of formatting binary bignums as decimal FP, and I can assure you that it is complex and difficult to do correctly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.