# C #define with 0

Tags: c, preprocessor

I have the following code:

```
#define HARDW 671                  // hardware 3 digits
#define FIRMW 013                  // firmware 3 digits
printf("FIRMW %d\r\n", FIRMW);
```

The result is 11 not 13.
Do you any explenation?
How could I transform the defined field to integer?
Note I use the field as a string too so I can not remove the 0....

Best regards
Mich

Comment: Integer constants starting from 0 are octal integer constants. So octal 013 is equal to decimal 11.

Comment: You could get rid of the leading `0` in your `#define` and use `printf("FIRMW %03d\r\n", FIRMW);`. This will print 3 digits with leading `0`s. See [printing leading 0s in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153890/printing-leading-0s-in-c).

Comment: You don't really intend for those to be numbers, but rather strings that happen to contain only digits. Don't use integer types for such values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, they explain why but I did not find any solution other than creating a new define without the 0....

Comment: Try `printf("FIRMW %03o\r\n", FIRMW);` and code will print 013. OK until `FIRMW 018`.

Answer (score 5):

The leading zero makes it an octal constant, just like a leading `0x` makes it a hexadecimal one, and a leading `0b` makes it a binary one (starting with C23).

- `13` produces the `int` thirteen (1*10+3),
- `0x13` produces the `int` nineteen (1*16+3),
- `0b11` produces the `int` three (1*2+1) [C23], and
- `013` produces the `int` eleven (1*8+3).